# How to convert unsigned long * params to ulong[] params

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, unmanaged, managed

I have an unmanaged code which is a type of:

```
unsigned long *inputParameters
```

I need to convert my variable inputparameters to C# type

```
 ulong[] inputParameters
```

I've tried different types of conversions like

```
auto inputParams = *((unsigned long*)inputParameters)
&inputParameters
```

however I am getting this exception:

> cannot convert argument  from 'unsigned long *' to 'cli::array<unsigned __int64,1> ^'

Comment: This is the exception cannot convert argument  from 'unsigned long *' to 'cli::array<unsigned __int64,1> ^'

Comment: You can't convert c/c++ `long` pointers to managed `ulong[]`.  You require `unsafe` code

Comment: You should format the error as code. That way the `<...>` don't get interpreted as HTML tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any types known in C# as reference types, need to be instantiated by using the `gcnew` keyword, arrays being no exception. Most value types are marashalled behind the scenes, so you can generally just assign managed to unmanged and vice versa without any casting or trickery. Magic, I know! There are some exception, but the compiler will let you know if there is an issue.

I am assuming that `*inputParameters` is a pointer list (rather than a pointer to a single value), which means that you should have a variable that contains the number of elements in the list, lets call it `nElements`. To do the conversion, you can do the following:

```
//some test data
int nElements = 10;
unsigned long *inputParameters = (unsigned long *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long) * nElements);

for (int i = 0; i < nElements; i++)
{
  *(inputParameters + i) = i * 2;//just arbitrary values
}

//now create a .NET array (lines below directly solve your question)
array<UInt64, 1>^ managedArray = gcnew array<UInt64, 1>(nElements);
for (int i = 0; i < nElements; i++)
{
  tempArray[i] = *(inputParameters + i);//this will be marshalled under the hood correctly. 
}
//now the array is ready to be consumed by C# code.
```

Here, `array<UInt64, 1>^` is the C++/CLI equivalent of C#'s `ulong[]`. You can return `managedArray` to a method call from C# that expects `ulong[]` as the return type.